# Send args from URL together with form in Flask

Tags: python, sql, forms, flask, args

Here's my problem, in short:
I have an URL that looks like this: **domain.tld/results?search_for=music**

On that page, I have a form with a select field, which I then submit to Flask to do some SQL with.

Basically, the form looks like this:

```
<form action="/filter" method="POST">
    <select name="sel_store">
        {% for store in stores %}
        <option value="{{ store }}">{{ store }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

And in the back, it looks like this:

```
@app.route("/filter", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def filter():
    search_for = request.args.get("search_for")
    store = request.form["sel_store"]
    return redirect(url_for("results", search_for=search_for, store=store))
```

(the **results** function does some SQL work with **search_for** and **store**, btw)

However, it doesn't seem to actually **get** any args from the URL, because it keeps giving me a NoneType object error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but I managed to get it working by doing this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('filtrare', search_for=request.args.get('search_for')) }}" method="POST">
```